# how to access an nameless object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im trying to understand how arrays work.
I cannot seem to access certain keys in an array.
the array is

```js
const array = [
 {
  username: "john",
  team: "red",
  score: 5,
  items: ["ball", "book", "pen"]
 },
 {
  username: "becky",
  team: "blue",
  score: 10,
  items: ["tape", "backpack", "pen"]
 }];
```

I tried to console.log(array.username) and also (this.array.username) and all the array['username'] variations. But it always returns undefined (or returns "cannot read property username of undefined."
But when i use "console.log (array[0].username)" it gives me the value.

so how can I access (or console.log) all the value of the "username" keys, without using an exact point like (array[0][1])?

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19590865/1823841

Comment: `const usernames = array.map(item => item.username)`

Comment: Please share your attempt after using different array iteration options.

Answer (score 0):

> so how can I access (or console.log) all the value of the "username"
>   keys, without using an exact point like (array[0])?

Use `map`

```
var allUserNames = array.map( s => s.username  )
```

Comment: thanks, but im trying to do it without any functions. just the data

Comment: @Codebebe *just the data* What does that mean?

Comment: I want to just console.log that data that is inside the array. in this case - the value of the "username" key.
With objects i could just say  - console.log(obj.username)
But it doesnt work for the array.
Either im doing something wrong, or one cannot access array data like access array like objects?

Comment: yes, since this is an array, you either will have to individually access those usernames by doing `array[0].username`, `array[1].username`, etc. or you need to iterate the array using **for-loop** or functions like `map` or `forEach`.